# Remove tag [ibm-text-to-speech]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [ibm-text-to-speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-text-to-speech) tag was created on June 30, 2017 and was not added as an official tag for the IBM service.

Our teams look for questions that are tagged [text-to-speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-to-speech) with either [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) or [ibm-watson-cognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-watson-cognitive). We are not searching for questions that are tagged [ibm-text-to-speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-text-to-speech).

I have checked the 11 questions that use the [ibm-text-to-speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-text-to-speech) tag. 10 of them are also tagged [text-to-speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-to-speech) and I have submitted an edit for the last one to change its [ibm-text-to-speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-text-to-speech) tag to [text-to-speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-to-speech).

Can someone please remove the [ibm-text-to-speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-text-to-speech) tag?

Comment: If removed from all questions it will be automatically deleted after 24h, I will check your edits and help you out with the removal.

Comment: I [left a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780671/ibm-text-to-speech-how-to-have-correct-pronounciation-of-english-words-in-germa#comment78601368_44780671) for the user who did the retags.

Answer (score 6):

Considering your reasoning, considering your user profile, considering that this tag just involves a very few questions (10) and was added later by a single user, I decided to not wait for meta support, but to simply remove it from the questions. ([Machavity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2370483/machavity) helped me out and left a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780671/ibm-text-to-speech-how-to-have-correct-pronounciation-of-english-words-in-germa#comment78601368_44780671) to the user that created and added the tag).

**The tag is now gone and will be deleted tomorrow.**

[image]

<sup>With 2K reputation, if there are so few questions in a tag and it is in your domain area, you can just go ahead and remove them, there is no need for an actual meta coordinated burnination.</sup>